# Converting query from SQL to pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert the following SQL query into pyspark:

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN COALESCE(data.pred,0) != 0 AND COALESCE(data.val,0) != 0 
    AND (ABS(COALESCE(data.pred,0) - COALESCE(data.val,0)) / COALESCE(data.val,0)) > 0.1
    THEN data.pred END) / COUNT(*) AS Result
```

The code I have in PySpark right now is this:

```
Result = data.select(
    count(
        (coalesce(data["pred"], lit(0)) != 0) & 
        (coalesce(data["val"], lit(0)) != 0) & 
        (abs(
             coalesce(data["pred"], lit(0)) - 
             coalesce(data["val"], lit(0))
            ) / coalesce(data["val"], lit(0)) > 0.1
        )
    )
)
aux_2 = aux_1.select(aux_1.column_name.cast("float"))

aux_3 = aux_2.head()[0]

Deviation = (aux_3 / data.count())*100
```

However, this is simply returning the number of rows in the "data" dataframe, and I know this isn't correct. I am very new at PySpark, can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `collect` the result into an integer, and then divide the numbers in Python:

```
Result = data.filter(
    (coalesce(data["pred"], lit(0)) != 0) & 
    (coalesce(data["val"], lit(0)) != 0) & 
    (abs(
         coalesce(data["pred"], lit(0)) - 
         coalesce(data["val"], lit(0))
        ) / coalesce(data["val"], lit(0)) > 0.1
    )
).count() / data.count()
```

Comment: I tried to implement that, but I obtained the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
I tried indexing the list but it also did not work... do you know what may be the solution?

Comment: @Johanna oops, sorry, I forgot to get the first element of the collected results.

Comment: PS: I edited the code in the question, I had forgotten the last part (the division part)

Comment: It is still returning the entire number of rows in the dataframe... at first I thought it was correct, but looking at the values I understand it is not

Comment: I am trying to find the quantity of rows for which the differene between "val" and "pred" is bigger than 10% and that are non null o NaN

Comment: I think the sql query doesn't give expected results because you're counting a bunch of boolean variables. You should filter the values that are true and count those only.